# MySQL CASE statement with varying data types

Tags: mysql

I have the code below (within Oracle BI)

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN 
Year("Assignment Inactive Date") = 4712 
       THEN 'THIS' 
         ELSE 'ELSE' 
       END 
FROM   thisTable
```

This works. `THIS` and `ELSE` are shown accordingly. However, if I change it to the following, I get the error error: `expected CHAR got DATE`

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN 
Year("Assignment Inactive Date") = 4712 
       THEN 'THIS' 
         ELSE "Assignment Inactive Date" 
       END 
FROM   thisTable
```

Lastly, if I do the following, everything is blank. The rows are returned, but everything is blank. Any ideas?

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN 
Year("Assignment Inactive Date") <> 4712 
       THEN "Assignment Inactive Date" 
       END 
FROM   thisTable
```

**Shows A and B**

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN
      year("Assignment Inactive Date") = 4712 
   THEN
      'A' 
   ELSE
      'B'
END
```

**Only shows the A's**

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN
      year("Assignment Inactive Date") = 4712 
   THEN
      'A' 
   ELSE
      CAST("Assignment Inactive Date" AS VARCHAR(20)) 
END
```

Comment: Try `ELSE CAST("Assignment Inactive Date" AS VARCHAR(20))`. All branches of `CASE ` have to be of save data type.

Comment: That was what was there originally (not included in above - apologies) and the above are my steps to produce a fix. Unfortunately, casting it brought back empty cells.

Comment: Have updated with two examples at the end

Comment: Have you enabled the "ANSI_QUOTES" SQL Mode? Is `"Assignment Inactive Date"` meant to be a string or a column?

Comment: It's a column with a timestamp data type